# How can I make prototype work with nodejs and protobufjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, protocol-buffers

I am too new to Prototype buffering. I am trying to use protobufjs with Nodejs, because I have the following Proto code in demo.proto. I just want to verify, encode, and send the request to the web socket.

```
message Logon { 
     required string user_name = 1; 
     required string password = 2; 
     optional string one_time_password = 3; 
     optional string private_label = 4; 
     required string client_id = 5; 
     required string client_version = 6;
     optional bool drop_concurrent_session = 7;
     optional uint32 collapsing_level = 8;
    optional uint32 protocol_version_minor = 9;
    optional uint32 protocol_version_major = 10;
}
```

My encoding function is following:

```
  async function encoderProto(buffer, command) {
    const root = await protobuf.load("democqg.proto");
    const testMessage = root.lookupType("WebAPI_1." + command);
    const err = testMessage.verify(buffer);
    if (err) {
        console.log("We got error");
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
    const message = testMessage.encode(buffer);
    return testMessage.toObject(message);
}
```

when I try to encode with the prototype, with the following request. I am getting an error saying "userName: string expected" I don't have UserName in Proto though, why it is saying "UserName" rather than "user_name". Is my JSON alright to verify? How can I make it work?

```
var logininfo = {
   "Logon" : {
      "user_name": "demoid",
      "password": "password!",
      "client_app_id": "ID",
      "client_version": "Version",
      "collapsing_level" : 0,
      "one_time_password": ""
    }
}
 var encoding = async () => {
    let encodingmsg = await encoderProto(logininfo, "Logon");
    return encodingmsg; 
}

    encoding().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    connection.send(data.toArrayBuffer());

});
```

Comment: I'd guess you have to pass `logininfo.Login` to `encoderProto`, not `logininfo`.

Comment: I even try with 
``` let encodingmsg = await encoderProto(logininfo.Logon, "Logon"); ``` it doesn't work though.